# How do you add Mylyn to an Eclipse package that does not already have it?

Tags: eclipse

I have a version of Ganymede that does not seem to have Mylyn installed.

Is it possible to add Mylyn without downloading a new version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to install like any other Eclipse plugin.

Go Help->Install New Software, add the Mylyn update site (found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/)).